# Adding category ID or slug to WP Nav Menu

Tags: menus

Is it possible to add the id or slug of a category in the output of wp_nav_menu menu's?

For example, the standard output of wp_nav_menu is:

```
<div class="menu-header">
    <ul id="menu-categorieen" class="menu">
        <li id="menu-item-4353" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-4353"><a href="http://domain/">Home</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-1034" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-1034"><a href="http://domain/category/category_1/">Category 1</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-1039" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-1039"><a href="http://domain/category/category_2/">Category 2</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-1032" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-1032"><a href="http://domain/category/category_3/">Category 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I'm wondering if it is possible to add the category slug to the css class for that `<li>`, like so:

```
<div class="menu-header">
    <ul id="menu-categorieen" class="menu">
        <li id="menu-item-4353" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-4353"><a href="http://domain/">Home</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-1034" class="menu-category-1 menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-1034"><a href="http://domain/category/category_1/">Category 1</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-1039" class="menu-category-2 menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-1039"><a href="http://domain/category/category_2/">Category 2</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-1032" class="menu-category-3 menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-1032"><a href="http://domain/category/category_3/">Category 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: add where? could you elaborate on what the desired results are?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the [`nav_menu_css_class`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/nav_menu_css_class) filter to add classes to `wp_nav_menu` output.

Add ID (no additional query needed):

```
function wpa_category_nav_class( $classes, $item ){
    if( 'category' == $item->object ){
        $classes[] = 'menu-category-' . $item->object_id;
    }
    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', 'wpa_category_nav_class', 10, 2 );
```

Add slug (loads category object via `get_category`):

```
function wpa_category_nav_class( $classes, $item ){
    if( 'category' == $item->object ){
        $category = get_category( $item->object_id );
        $classes[] = 'menu-' . $category->slug;
    }
    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', 'wpa_category_nav_class', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: i had the same issue, but i needed the slug of my page. this thread helped me a lot. here is the solution:
`function my_special_nav_class( $classes, $item ) {
  if( 'page' == $item->object ){
    $page = get_post( $item->object_id );
    $classes[] = $page->post_name;
  }
  return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', 'my_special_nav_class', 10, 2 );`

Comment: The difference between `$item->ID` and `$item->object_id` is key here. Nice answer!

Comment: to prevent the additional query, you could use `sanitize_title($item->title)` instead of getting the category slug